# Comparing different degrees of local spatial association

Tags: spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

I have two data sets and want to compare/evaluate their degree of spatial association expressed in terms of the LISA statistic.

The local Moran's I statistic gives for each point a (pseudo) p-Value and a correlation coefficient. I want to make a statement like "The points of data set a are more locally correlated than the points of data set b". To do so I though of simply comparing the sum of the absolute values of the significant (p<0.05) correlation coefficients.

Do you think this is a valid approach? Alternatively it might be also reasonable to form the squared sum in order to give more weight to large coefficients.